# DirectoryEntry safe password handling

Tags: c#, .net, security, active-directory, directoryentry

The DirectoryEntry class requires username and password to be passed in as a string in cleartext. In c#, strings are generally not safe when used for storing sensitive data (there is no way to zero out the memory after use). How can I safely use DirectoryEntry to query the active directory without risking leaving the username in password in the memory?

I do understand that the memory used to store this data will be released back to the heap after use, but it will not be cleared!

If I'm wrong about any of my assertions, please let me know.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wh2h7eed(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Why does your class require passwords in clear text? That seems counterproductive.

Comment: OP is refering to System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry which takes password as cleartext.

Comment: My class requires that passwords are NEVER stored in cleartext unless you can clear the memory after use (such as a char or byte array).Since System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry requires cleartext credentials, I see this as a security problem.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to query LDAP or AD in .NET with credentials that doesn't use plain text.

If you don't want to store passwords in memory then don't use them, give the user(s) the application runs under the rights to do what you need and use windows authentication instead.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most secure way is to run the application under the credentials you need to access AD with. If it's a desktop application, then that's easy (just run-as the application with the appropriate credentials).

In ASP.NET, it's a little trickier, but can be done with impersonation (either for the whole request, or just for a section of code): https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/306158/how-to-implement-impersonation-in-an-asp-net-application

Comment: This means basically the same as Ashigore's answer. I would be interested to know why Corey thinks he needs user+pw. Does this run under a non-AD account or perhaps as as service under SYSTEM from a non-domain member ?